# 960gs issue on columns

Tags: html, css, grid, 960.gs

I want to make a page like this in 960 gs 12 col
[image: What to design]

I wrote html:

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_6"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="grid_6"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>

    <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="grid_1 suffix_6"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

but this looks like this:
[image: what is showing]

any idea, how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each grid will have a margin and is displayed as inline. You will need to put each set of divs into a separate column and use the alpha omega classes to remove the margins on the first/last divs respectively.

```
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_6">
      <div class="grid_6 alpha omega"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid_1 alpha"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid_1"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
      <div class="grid_1 omega"><img src="images/x.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_6">
  <img src="images/x.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```